# Values are in text view not passed to the Mysql database

Tags: php, android, mysql, android-fragments, android-intent

In my android app i am getting latitude and longitude for textview and then i m trying to pass them to the Mysql DB.MySql Db has created locally..My db has 3 fields id(auto incremented) latitude and longitude(double).No log cat errores

Here is My Main Activity

```
package com.example.newgps;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

  LocationManager lm;
  TextView lt, ln;
  String provider;
  Location l;
  int code;
  InputStream is=null;
  String result=null;
  String line=null;
  Button button1;
  String latitude;
  String longitude;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ln=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lng);
   lt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lat);
   Button button1=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

   button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
            latitude= lt.getText().toString();
            longitude = ln.getText().toString();

            insert();
        }
    });

   lm=(LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
   Criteria c=new Criteria();

   provider=lm.getBestProvider(c, false);

   l=lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
   if(l!=null)
   {
     //get latitude and longitude of the location
     double lng=l.getLongitude();
     double lat=l.getLatitude();


     ln.setText(""+lng);
     lt.setText(""+lat);
   }
   else
   {
    ln.setText("No Provider");
    lt.setText("No Provider");
   }
  }

   @Override
   public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0)
   {
    double lng=l.getLongitude();
    double lat=l.getLatitude();
    ln.setText(""+lng);
    lt.setText(""+lat);
   }




   public void insert ()
   {
    final ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude",latitude));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude",longitude));

    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        private Exception exception;
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

    try
    {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.31/gpstracking/insert.php");
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost); 
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            Log.e("pass 1", "connection success ");
    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Fail 1", e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid IP Address",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }     

       try
       {
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
        {
               sb.append(line + "\n");
           }
           is.close();
           result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("pass 2", "connection success ");
    }
       catch(Exception e)
    {
           Log.e("Fail 2", e.toString());
    }     

    try
    {
           JSONObject json_data = new JSONObject(result);
           code=(json_data.getInt("code"));

           if(code==1)
           {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Inserted Successfully",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           }
           else
           {
         Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Sorry, Try Again",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
           Log.e("Fail 3", e.toString());
    }
    return latitude;

    }
    }}
  @Override
  public void onProviderDisabled(String arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
  @Override
  public void onProviderEnabled(String arg0) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(String arg0, int arg1, Bundle arg2) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
}
```

Here is my Php script

```
    <?php


        $host='localhost';
        $uname='root';
        $pwd='';
        $db="gps";

        $con = mysql_connect($host,$uname,$pwd) or die("connection failed");
        mysql_select_db($db,$con) or die("db selection failed");

        $latitude=$_REQUEST['latitude'];
        $longitude=$_REQUEST['longitude'];

        $flag['code']=0;

        if($r=mysql_query("insert into location values('$latitude','$longitude') ",$con))
        {
            $flag['code']=1;
            echo"hi";
        }

        print(json_encode($flag));
        mysql_close($con);
    ?>
```

Comment: use asyncTask when make HTTP call check this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9671546/asynctask-android-example

Comment: use AsyncTask for doing network action in background thread

Comment: @Anup Dasari can u tell me exactly which part that i need to edit from above code?

Comment: @colombo your method insert() must be in AsyncTask

Comment: @AnupDasari i have add asynctask but still values not passed to the MYSQL db

Comment: @colombo your implementation is wrong. Please read the documentation if you are not familiar with AsyncTask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 0):

Using asyncTask is best for Network operation.But you can overcome `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` by adding this in your `oncreate` method..

```
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

this will remove your `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`
but best programming is to use `asyncTask`